# Using Javascript with HTA

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I would like to know if I am able to use plain JavaScript with HTML applications. I have tried making a simple application, but I get an error when opening the HTA document. The error states "Object does not support property or method 'addEventListener'". My question is if JavaScript methods and functions ("addEventListener" for example) can be used within HTA documents.

I have posted all of the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hta game</title>
        <HTA:APPLICATION 
            applicationname="game" 
            border="no" 
            singleinstance="yes" 
            scroll="no"
        />
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            .ga {
                width: 845px;
                height: 623px;
                border: 2px dashed blueviolet;
                background: black;
            }

            .plyr {
                position: absolute;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                margin-left: 1px;
                top: 579px;
                background: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gameArea" class="ga">
            <div id="player" class="plyr"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = (function main(){
            window.resizeTo(880, 680);

            (function game(){
                setup();
            })();

            function setup(){
                (function playerFunctions(){
                    function moveControls(){
                        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                            switch (event.keyCode) {
                            case 37: // Left
                                player.offsetLeft = 20 + "px";
                            break;

                            case 38: // Up
                                player.offsetHeight = 20 + "px";
                            break;

                            case 39: // Right
                                player.offsetLeft = -20 + "px";
                            break;

                            case 40: // Down
                                player.offsetHeight = -20 + "px";
                            break;
                            }
                        }, false);
                    }moveControls();
                })();
            }
        })();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try adding the listener to the document or document.body or your #gameArea instead to see what would happen? Just an idea

Comment: HTAs run in IE7 compatibility mode by default, but if you add IE=Edge then the HTA-specific meta and APPLICATION elements don't work. The situation sucks.

Comment: I just tried that now, I am still seeing the same error @CertainPerformance

Comment: Not easy to find documentation about JavaScript with HTA. I've found something about scripting HTA with VBScript, the API looks quite close to the API provided by a web browser : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx.

Comment: you can certainly use Javascript, otherwise you wouldn't have got as far as getting the error - that comes from the JS interpreter. But precisely what version of JS (and therefore what's supported) may be an issue. This will also depend on what Windows version you execute it on, as to what version of IE's Trident engine it uses to run the HTA.  From memory I think I did a JS one, but used jQuery to abstract away all the compatibility stuff. That seemed to work ok.

Comment: I am using a windows 7 os. I believe that to be why some of the javascript works but other stuff like 'addEventListener' will not work unless i have IE-9 or newer.

Comment: you can install anything up to IE11 on Windows 7. Is that not possible for you / your users?